# repo sync error: .repo/manifests/: contains uncommitted changes

Tags: git, repo

After issued `repo sync`, I got a error message like `error: .repo/manifests/: contains uncommitted changes`, but `git status` or `git diff` showed nothing changed.

What's cause of the problem and why it happened?

Comment: `git reset --hard` and then `repo sync`

Comment: What does `git diff --cached` show you?

Comment: nothing showed. and git status tells my branch is consistent with remote branch

Comment: go to `.repo/manifests/` and then `git reset --hard`

Comment: Find the root cause,  all files under .repo/manifests were changed their filemode, git config core.filemode false can fix this "Modify".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Find the root cause, all files under .repo/manifests were changed with their filemode, "git config core.filemode false" can fix this "Modify".

Comment: After another problem, I had to change all file modes in my home directory. It affected of course a repository in my home directory. I run that command in order file modes to be ignored by git and it worked :)

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to ./repo/manifests
2. $ git reset --hard
3. $ repo sync

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command `repo diff` or `repo status` to find which of the child git repositories it is which is broken. It might not be the sub-repository you think it is.

Comment: 进入到./repo/mannifest文件夹。执行git status就能看到却别。很可能不是你认为的子仓库有变化。

Answer (score 0):

make sure you don’t have another .repo directory in parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

Commit your changes under `.repo/manifests/` by doing the following commands from the project root's folder:

```
cd .repo/manifests/
git commit -a -m "Very Informative Title"
```